# How to allow a member function that's defined inside the class declaration to be called by constant objects of said class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have a `Book` class within a namespace literature and the following declaration implementation pair doesn't work:

```
namespace literature
{
    class Book{
    public:
        //Getter method
        Condition check(){return status;} const

        bool operator==(const Book&);
        bool operator!=(const Book&);
    }
}
```

The logical overload's declaration:

```
namespace literature{
    bool Book::operator==(const Book& right)
    {return true;}

    bool Book::operator!=(const Book& right)
    {return false;}
}
```

For some reason, the implementation for operator `!=` works while the one for `==` doesn't and instead states that the prototype for the `==` overload returns a `const bool` instead of `bool`

Comment: @Jarod42 Did you change anything? Because it still doesn't work on my pc

Comment: Could you provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: @coincoin added under EDIT 2

Comment: @J.Alvaro.T you better open new file, rewrite your code there and try to reproduce your own problem by yourself. Because it is not reproducable, so, obviously, you have a problem on your side.

Comment: Your `==` operator is a class member in the header but not in the implementation.

Comment: @AndyBrown oops sorry wrong example in EDIT 2

Comment: if you edited it correctly, i think the problem is, your operator== is not a member of book, looking at your edited post.

Comment: Show your correct implementation indeed you re missing Book:: here :  `bool Book::operator==(const Book& right)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the answer from J.Alvaro.T shows what was done to overcome his problem. But the answer text is misleading. The main issue is that this line of code:

`Condition check() {return status;} const`

is grammatically malformed. The intention was to make this method a const method and for that the const keyword should appear before the function body. Any characters after the function body are not parsed as part of function definition and become part of the next statement.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the problem and I won't delete this post for others. It turns out the problem is on the previous line which is:

```
Condition check() {return status;} const

bool operator==(const Book&);
```

For others out there with the same problem it turns out if you want to define a function within the declaration of a class and allow const objects of said class to call it you should do the following instead:

```
Condition check() const {return status;}

bool operator==(const Book&);
```

Comment: It looks that your problem was indeed in previous line (like often in C or C++).  This line `Condition check() {return status;} const` was read as `Condition check() {return status;}` and next became  `const bool operator==(const Book&);`. That alone fully explains your error. Don't forget, newlines are nice for humans to read, but compiler doesn't care too much for them ...

Comment: For info, your first snippet is parsed as `const bool operator==(const Book&);` (return a `const bool`). So the mismatch between declaration and definition.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Yup. That's why I'll leave the question here so anyone who has the same problem can find out why.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes. I didn't know where to put the `const` keyword before.

Comment: @J.Alvaro.T: To be useful for future reader, you have to edit your question to show the problem.

Comment: @J.Alvaro.T : and also edit above answer. Comments are only second class citizens ...

Comment: @Jarod42  Yup. Did what you advised

Comment: You see how it is important to provide a minimal example. Your minimal example in original question is not complete and there is no way the community can guess the missing code. Regarding keeping this post, the problem is that title of the post does not suggest anything about the actual issue and will be difficult to find anyway!